# Get checkbox values in array according to parent div ;jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a 3 Divs with checkboxes in it.

```
   <div id="MyDiv1">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="1"  />
    <input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="2"  />
    <input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="3"  />
    </div>

    <div id="MyDiv2">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="1"  />
    <input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="2"  />
    <input type="checkbox"  name="newCheckboxes" value="3"  />
    </div>
```

I also have a working code to get all the values in an array

```
    function updateTextArea() {

           var allVals = [];
           var parent = $(this).parent("div");


           $('#c_b :checked').each(function () {

               allVals.push($(this).val());
           });
           var removeItem = 'on';
           allVals = jQuery.grep(allVals, function (value) {
               return value != removeItem;
           });

          //Set Value of hidden Field
           $("#<%= hfSearchData.ClientID %>").val(allVals);


       }
       $(function () {

           $('#c_b input').click(updateTextArea);
           updateTextArea();
       });`
```

Now I want to separate the Values in different arrays according to Divs

ex. Array 1 for Mydiv1; array 2 for Mydiv2

I tried checking parent div but not useful

Thanks.